# Dynamically change layout from activity android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

in my project i am changing from listview layout to gridview layout dynamically, by calling setcontentview() twice on action bar button click . and i also have action bar with a button and a sliding menu .Changing from one layout to another and visa versa is working fine but after that action bar sliding menu stopped working. 
here is my code where i am changing layout

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        if(list)
        {
            list = false ;
            grid = true;
            setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            arrayAdapter = new EventsListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            gridview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            actionbar();
        }
        else if(grid)
        {
            grid = false;
            list = true;
            setContentView(R.layout.eventsdetails);
            eventList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.EventsList);
            arrayAdapter = new EventsListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            eventList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            actionbar();
        }
        break;
    case android.R.id.home:
    {
        menu.toggle();
    }
    default:
        break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    private void actionbar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);

        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getSlidingMenu()` instead of creating new one